# Epsilon delta combined with supremum

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and that $f(x)\le f(y)$ whenever $x< y$. (Such a function is usually said to be increasing, even though $f(x)$ could be equal to $f(y)$). Let $a\in \mathbb{R}$.

Let $S=\{ f(x): x<a\}$.

Let $m=\sup S$.

Prove: For all $\epsilon>0$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that if $a-\delta<x<a$ then $m-\epsilon< f(x) \le m$.

I know $f(a)$ is an upper bound of $S$, since $x<a$ and $f(x)\le f(a)$.

So I know that $m\le f(a)$.

I know since "there exists" an $\epsilon$ I have to construct a $\delta$ that proves the statement.

I am not sure how to do so, I have seen $\epsilon \delta$ proofs before, but this one is very confusion to me.

Comment: The maximum and minimum of finitely many upper semicontinuous functions is upper semicontinuous, and the same holds true of lower semicontinuous functions. see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-continuity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's (as always) start with some $\epsilon > 0$. Now, looking at $m - \epsilon$, what do we know? As $m$ is the supremum of $S$, that is the least upper bound, $m-\epsilon$ is no upper bound for $S$. That is, there is some element of $S$, hence an $f(x_0)$ with $x_0 < a$ such that $f(x_0) > m - \epsilon$. Now let $\delta := a - x_0 > 0$. If we now are given an $x$ with $a - \delta (=x_0) < x < a$, we have 
$$ m - \epsilon < f(x_0) \stackrel{\text{$f$ increasing}}\le f(x) \le m $$
as we wanted.

Comment: Thank you for the response! How is it we know that $x>x_0$?

Comment: $a-\delta = x_0$. And we are only interested in $x$ with $x > a-\delta$.

Comment: Oh yes, I see now thank you!